# Detect SQL injection in Groovy dynamic SQL

Tags: security, grails, groovy, sql-injection

How can you detect SQL injection vulnerability in a Grails app with dynamic native SQL?

What I'm looking for is something that can tell the difference between this

```
def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
def dynamicWhereClause = ""
if (params.col) {
   dynamicWhereClause = " and col = :col"
}
// OK because dynamic SQL does not concatenate user input
def sqlString = "select * from tab where ... ${dynamicWhereClause}"
sql.rows(sqlString, params)
```

and this

```
def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
def dynamicWhereClause = ""
if (params.col) {
   // NOT OK - directly concatenating user input
   dynamicWhereClause = " and col = '" + params.col + "'"
}
def sqlString = "select * from tab where ... ${dynamicWhereClause}"
sql.rows(sqlString)
```

Sonarqube/Findbugs has a rule like "prepared statement is generated from a nonconstant String" but that would not distinguish between the safe one and the dangerous one.  What other options are out there?

Comment: Code reviews perhaps?

Comment: Yup, code reviews and training is our main defense at present, and I'm looking for a backstop to provide some reassurance in case something slips through.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [Static Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tool such as ["Find Security Bugs"](http://h3xstream.github.io/find-sec-bugs/).

[See here](http://samate.nist.gov/index.php/Source_Code_Security_Analyzers.html) for others that are compatible with Groovy.

Comment: SonarQube has plugins for Groovy (docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Groovy+Plugin) and FindBugs, but does not appear to support both at the same time.  I'm starting to think that there are just inherent limits to what you can do with static analysis in such a dynamic environment.